# induction hypothesis for even numbers

Tags: coq, induction

I am trying to write an induction hypothesis specifically for proving properties of **even numbers**. I formulated and proved the following:

```
Theorem ind_hyp_on_evens:
forall (p : nat -> Prop), 
(p 0 -> (forall n, p n -> p (S (S n))) -> 
forall n, p (n + n)). 
Proof.
intros p P0 P1.
intro n.
assert(p (n + n) /\ p (S (S (n + n)))). 
induction n as [| n'].  
split. unfold plus. assumption.
unfold plus. 
apply (P1 0).
assumption.
destruct IHn' as [A B]. 
split. 
rewrite <- plus_Snm_nSm.
rewrite -> ? plus_Sn_m.
assumption. 
rewrite <- plus_Snm_nSm.
rewrite -> ? plus_Sn_m.
apply (P1 (S (S (n' + n')))).
assumption. 
destruct H as [H1 H2].
assumption. Qed.
```

Despite the fact that it's proved, any attempt to use it results in the error message: "Error: Not the right number of induction arguments."

Can someone please tell me what is the problem with the induction hypothesis, or otherwise, how to apply it??

Thanks,

Mayer

Comment: How did you attempt to apply it? Post your code that led to the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `induction` assumes that any induction principle that will be used has the
fixed form

```
forall ... (P : SomeType -> Type) ..., (* or ->Set or ->Prop *)
   ... ->
   forall (v : SomeType), P v
```

Your `ind_hyp_on_evens` matches only `P (plus n n)` which seems to confuse `induction`.

If you have a suitable goal, say `forall n, is_even (n+n)`, you can manually do the
steps that `induction` normally does and extend that to handle the special form.

```
intro n0;                            (* temp. var *)
pattern (n0 + n0);                   (* restructure as (fun x => (is_even x)) (n0+n0) *)
refine (ind_hyp_on_evens _ _ _ n0);  (* apply ind. scheme *)
clear n0; [| intros n IHn ].         (* clear temp., do one 'intros' per branch *)
```

I don't know if it's possible to pack that up as a general helper tactic for any induction scheme, packing these steps up as a per-scheme `Ltac` tactic should work however.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing an inductive predicate that describes even numbers (code not tested):

```
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
| evenO : even O
| evenSSn : forall n, even n -> even (S (S n))
.
```

Coq will generate the induction principle automatically.
You would have to prove that `even n` holds before being able to perform induction on the "evenness" of n.

Comment: This is correct, though you could equally well imagine writing the induction principle by hand using a simple Fixpoint definition, without going by way of introducing an auxiliary predicate.